# Extract values using parallelStream in Java

Tags: java, json, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have this json Array:

```
"LiveSessionDataCollection": [
    {
      "CreateDate": "2017-12-27T13:29:06.595Z",
      "Data": "Khttp://www8.hp.com/us/en/large-format-printers/designjet-printers/products.html&AbSGOX+SGOXpLXpBF8CXpGOA9BFFPconsole.info('DeploymentConfigName%3DRelease_20171227%26Version%3D1')%3B&HoConfig: Release_20171227&AwDz//////8NuaCh63&Win32&SNgYAJBBYWCYKW9a&2&SGOX+SGOXpF/1en-us&AAAAAAAAAAAAQICBCXpGOAAMBBBB8jl",
      "DataFlags": 8,
      "DataFlagType": 264,
      "LegacyLiveSessionDataType": null,
      "LiveSessionId": 1545190526042650,
      "MessageNumber": 0,
      "StreamId": 0,
      "StreamMessageId": 0,
      "ProjectId": 201
    },
    {
      "CreateDate": "2017-12-27T13:29:08.887Z",
      "Data": "oDB Information Level : Detailed&9BbRoDB Annual Sales : 55000000&BoDB Audience : Mid-Market Business&AoDB%20Audience%20Segment%20%3A%20Retail%20%26%20Distribution&AoDB B2C : true&AoDB Company Name : Clicktale Inc&AoDB SID : 120325490&AoDB Employee Count : 275&AoDB Employee Range : Mid-Market&AoDB%20Industry%20%3A%20Retail%20%26%20Distribution&AoDB Revenue Range : $50M - $100M&AoDB Sub Industry : Electronics&AoDB Traffic : High&AWB9tY/8bvOBBP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"w:auto;l:auto;\"},\"n\":\"div53\"}]})&sP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"w:auto;l:auto;\"},\"n\":\"div62\"}]})&FP_({\"r\":[\"script2\"],\"m\":[{\"n\":{\"nt\":1,\"tn\":\"SCRIPT\",\"a\":{\"async\":\"\",\"src\":\"http://admin.brightcove.com/js/api/SmartPlayerAPI.js?_=1514381348598\"},\"i\":\"script55\"},\"t\":false,\"pn\":\"head1\"}]})&8GuP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"t:0px;mt:0px;l:274.5px;ml:0px;\"},\"n\":\"div442\"}]})&SP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"t:0px;mt:0px;l:274.5px;ml:0px;\"},\"n\":\"div444\"}]})&D",
      "DataFlags": 8,
      "DataFlagType": 264,
      "LegacyLiveSessionDataType": null,
      "LiveSessionId": 1545190526042650,
      "MessageNumber": 1,
      "StreamId": 0,
      "StreamMessageId": 1,
      "ProjectId": 201
    },
    {
      "CreateDate": "2017-12-27T13:29:08.971Z",
      "Data": "P_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div105\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div114\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div123\"}]})&9B+8P_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div167\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div169\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div178\"}]})&JP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:457px;\"},\"n\":\"div220\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:457px;\"},\"n\":\"div229\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:457px;\"},\"n\":\"div238\"}]})&FP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div282\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div291\"},{\"a\":{\"s\":\"mih:480px;\"},\"n\":\"div300\"}]})&HP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"t:0px;mt:-92px;l:274.5px;ml:0px;\"},\"n\":\"div442\"}]})&HP_({\"a\":[{\"a\":{\"s\":\"t:0px;mt:-92px;l:274.5px;ml:0px;\"},\"n\":\"div444\"}]})&B",
      "DataFlags": 8,
      "DataFlagType": 264,
      "LegacyLiveSessionDataType": null,
      "LiveSessionId": 1545190526042650,
      "MessageNumber": 2,
      "StreamId": 0,
      "StreamMessageId": 2,
      "ProjectId": 201
    }]
```

And I am trying to get all `DataFlagType` values using `parallelStream()` and `forEach()`.

This is the code I have written but I am getting error:

```
jsonArray = (JSONArray) json.get("LiveSessionDataCollection");
jsonArray.parallelStream().forEach(
    x -> ((JSONObject) dataFlagType = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(1)));
```

I don't know exactly how to work with `parallelStream()`. How can I achieve getting all `DataFlayType` values from the json array (as `int`)?

Comment: The 'x' you have inside your forEach is a JsonObject inside your JsonArray. Why do you try to access .get on your JsonArray ?

Comment: I am sorry did not understand your question.

Comment: for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.size();i++){
            JSONObject rec = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
            String flagDataType = rec.get("DataFlagType").toString();
            System.out.println(flagDataType);
        }

I am trying to do the same thing as I did in the "for loop" but i want to use parallel Stream to get all values in parallel and not one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get a stream of all object's DataFlagType attribute then collect it in a list:

`jsonArray.parallelStream().map(x->
  ((JSONObject)x).get("DataFlagType")).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Output:

[264,264,264]

Comment: Great! thanks! now I want to understand how to work with parallel streams if I want to check if the output is as expected and to continue manipulate the result (for example if output is 265 I want to perform an action).